# Javascript Disable button and reenable it after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript

I want to disable my button on click and then reenable in after 5 seconds but its not working properly.

```
  function submitPoll(id){
      document.getElementById("votebutton").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("votebutton").delay(5000).disabled = false;
  }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`.delay` is jQuery. You can simply use `setTimeout` in Javascript.

```
function submitPoll(id){
      document.getElementById("votebutton").disabled = true;
      setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("votebutton").disabled = false;},5000);
  }
```

Comment: This helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Like Zee said `.delay` is a JQuery function which can only be used on a JQuery object. Currently you are only using a reference to an HTML element which is produced by `.getElementById()`

If you are wanting a button that disables itself. I went ahead and made a little example on jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/1z0bx0t7/

Using code that looks like:

```
function submitPoll() {
    document.getElementById("votebutton").disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("votebutton").disabled = false;
    }, 5000);
}
document.getElementById("votebutton").addEventListener("click", submitPoll);
```