# How to TEMORARILY disable a button from being pushed again

Tags: javascript, button, timer, settimeout

I made a simple prompt generator for virtual Pictionary games with friends. The user clicks a button and gets a prompt to draw. I would like to have the button be disabled for a minute or so, to prevent the user from clicking the button again if they don't like their first prompt.

I'm very new to coding and haven't had much luck finding a solution. I know the setTimout() method will run an expression after a given time, but how do I do I do the inverse and prevent that expression from happening for a given time instead? Any advice is appreciated.

The only function I have so far is below, it simply randomizes a prompt from an array. The button executes the function onClick in the html, then returns the result in a text box.

````
  document.getElementById("textbox").value = prompts[Math.floor(Math.random() * prompts.length)];
}```
````

Comment: So, disabled the button for x amount of time...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Disable button and reenable it after 5 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30558587/javascript-disable-button-and-reenable-it-after-5-seconds)

Answer (score 1):

You can use what we call a "flag". In this case, the flag will be a variable you set to true or false to indicate if the user can click or not *(the `canClick` variable in the below example)*. Whenever the user clicks, check the flag before executing your function. And use `setTimeout` to reset the flag after a delay:

```js
var prompts = ["Cow", "Dog", "Cat", "Rat", "Owl"],
    canClick = true,
    clickDelay = 2 * 1000, // 2 seconds for the demo
    generateBtn = document.getElementById('generate-btn'),
    textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");

generateBtn.addEventListener('click', onBtnClick);

function onBtnClick() {
  if (canClick) {
    canClick = false;
    generateBtn.disabled = true;
    displayRandomPrompt();
    // After a delay
    setTimeout(function() {
      canClick = true;
      generateBtn.disabled = false;
    }, clickDelay);
  }
}

function displayRandomPrompt() {
  textbox.value = prompts[Math.floor(Math.random() * prompts.length)];
}
```

```html
<input id="textbox" />
<button id="generate-btn">New suggestion</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/keoxn51p/

```
  button.disabled = true
  setTimeout(() => {
    button.disabled = false
  }, 60000)
```

Set your button to disabled and then run a function to remove that state in 60s.