# Javascript: disable submit button for X seconds

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I would like to disable a submit button after it has been clicked. I.e. I do not want to call the function which is triggered by the click if I click within few seconds (3s in the example). I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30558587/javascript-disable-button-and-reenable-it-after-5-seconds) and tried to implement it on my code.

```
document.getElementById("butS").addEventListener("click",submit);
document.getElementById("butS").addEventListener("click",disableS);

   function disableS(){
      document.getElementById("butS").disabled = true;
      setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("butS").disabled = false;},3000);
  }
```

I am not sure why it does not work. I am still able to click the button and trigger the function "submit". So I am wondering if the disable is actually disabling this string:

```
document.getElementById("butS").addEventListener("click",submit);
```

EDIT: I have not defined the button correctly. I had:

```
<a id="butS">Submit</a>
```

while I should have had:

```
<button id="butS">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Can you make an [mcve] of the logic that does not work?

Comment: Also, you don't need to continually query for the element: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qoLdtncx/)

Comment: Why 3 seconds? There is a good chance 3 seconds is completely arbitrary and likely incorrect.

Comment: @Phix You could also cut out the repeated lookup at the start.

Comment: @Taplar indeed, done! [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wt4kau2s/)

Comment: Thank you so much for all your answers. You example made me realize I have not defined a button. I am not using <button id="butS">Submit</button>. I am using <a id="butS" > Submit</a>. Sorry, I am new with coding and never realized I defined it incorrectly since the beginning. It was working and never bothered again. Out of curiosity, is there a way to disable that "button" even if not defined properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript is fine (aside from scanning the DOM over and over to get the button reference, which you only need to do once), but you may not be correctly referencing your HTML `submit` button. Make sure that your `script` is located just prior to your closing `body` tag so that by the time it is encountered, all the HTML will have been parsed into memory. If your script is running prior to the button being parsed, you won't get a reference to it.

As you can see here, as long as you reference the button correctly, your code works.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="butS">Submit</button>

  <!-- By placing the script just before the closing of the body
       you ensure that all the DOM elements will have been parsed
       into memory and are accessible by the script. -->
  <script>
    // Just get the reference to your button one time
    // it's a waste to keep looking for the same element
    const button = document.getElementById("butS");
    button.addEventListener("click",submit);
    button.addEventListener("click",disableS);

    function disableS(){
      button.disabled = true;
      setTimeout(function(){ button.disabled = false; }, 3000);
    }

    function submit(){

    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I checked my code, it is very long and I cannot show it here, but I confirm that the script is within the body as you have shown. I noticed a difference though. I am not using <button id="butS">Submit</button>. I am using <a id="butS" > Button</a>. So I guess the propriety disable does not work because I have not defined it as a button.. I could change it to a button, but out of curiosity, is there a way to disable the "bottom" as I have defined it?

Comment: An `a` is an "anchor" or a hyperlink. You can prevent it from being clicked by giving it the CSS of `pointer-events:none;`.