# Disable Button for one minute when it's clicked

Tags: javascript, html, timer, settimeout, disable

I am trying to make a button that will be disabled for 1 minute when you click on it.
Only when the button is enabled and you click on it, 25 points should be added to a div (div starts at 0).
After each click, the button will be disabled and the timer will start running.

Here are some pictures to make the whole thing a bit more understandable:

[image: Timer starts at 1:00 and is disabled]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code of what you have tried so far? What exactly is the problem you are facing? Note that SO and its members are not a coding-service.

Comment: You can check older solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30558587/javascript-disable-button-and-reenable-it-after-5-seconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could create a [Custom Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements).
This requires knowledge in the following topics:

- [Event Listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [JavaScript Class-syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)
- [Inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance)
- Timing mechanisms, for example with [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) and [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)
- Optional: The [Shadow Root](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot) and its [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM)

## Basic structure

Defining a *custom element* requires a JS *class* that extends [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) (or one of its sub-classes).

This class is then registered as an HTML-element by calling [`customElements.define()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define) with its HTML-element name (must include `-` (hyphen) *in* its name, e.g. "example-element") and the class it is associated with.

I decided to call the class `CounterElement`, and the HTML-element `<counter-instance>`:

```js
class CounterElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super(); // Required since we are extending a class
  }
}
customElements.define('counter-instance', CounterElement);
```

## Setting up the Shadow Root

Setting up the Shadow Root is done like this:

1. Create the shadow root by calling [`Element.attachShadow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow)
2. Create and append its HTML-elements
3. Add styling to the shadow root

Since some comment mentioned that accessing the elements would still be easy, I decided to use `{mode: 'closed'}` to keep unknowing users from accessing them. It is, however, **not inaccessible**. That would require a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), but that is not included in this answer to keep it (somewhat) short, *heh*.

When using `{mode: 'closed'}`, one needs to keep a reference to the shadow root manually. I decided to use a private member-variable `#shadow`.

Now, the shadow root's elements need to be created and appended. Again, I kept a private reference for the "important" elements: `#samp` and `#button`.

I also added a little bit of styling.

```js
class CounterElement extends HTMLElement {
  #shadow;
  #samp;
  #button;
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    // Shadow Root
    this.#shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'closed'});
    
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    let style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML = 'div{padding:0.2rem;border:1px solid black}'
        + 'samp{display:block}button{font-family:monospace}';
    
    this.#samp = document.createElement('samp');
    this.#button = document.createElement('button');
    
    div.append(this.#samp, this.#button);
    this.#shadow.append(style, div);
  }
}
customElements.define('counter-instance', CounterElement);
```

## Setting up the elements

Now that all the important elements exist, we need to set them up correctly. By that, I mean add the texts they should have.

Since we will keep track of a counter and seconds, declaring them as member-variables makes sense.

To format the seconds to a `mm:ss`-format, I wrote a utility function `formatTime()`. That seems quite handy, so it can be in the global scope.
**Note** that you should try not to clutter the global scope with too many variables. You can use [IIFEs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to keep them local.

Now, adding the text is as easy as using [`HTMLElement.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText).

In a comment you requested to have the button say "Collect" when the seconds have reached 0. This can be done using an if-else statement, but for brevity I used the [Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```js
function formatTime(seconds) {
  var min = new String(Math.floor(seconds / 60));
  var sec = new String(seconds % 60);

  while (min.length < 2) min = '0' + min;
  while (sec.length < 2) sec = '0' + sec;

  return min + ':' + sec;
};

class CounterElement extends HTMLElement {
  counter = 0;
  seconds = 0;
  #shadow;
  #samp;
  #button;
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    // Shadow Root
    // ...
    
    this.updateText();
  }
  
  updateText() {
    this.#samp.innerText = this.counter;
    this.#button.innerText = this.seconds ? formatTime(this.seconds) : 'Collect';
  }
}
customElements.define('counter-instance', CounterElement);
```

## Adding (the timer) functionality

The last step now is to add the timer, and the `onclick`-listener.

Since we want to start a timer when clicking on `#button`, and stop it after `seconds` reaches `0`, we can use `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()` respectively.

The former function returns the interval's ID, the latter clears it using its ID. To use these functions as intended, we need to keep a reference to the interval's ID.

When `#button` is clicked, it should:

- Reset `seconds` and increase `counter`
- Start our timer
- Be disabled for the duration of our timer
- Update texts respecting the now-resetted values

Here is our (shortened) code implementing it:

```js
// function formatTime(seconds) () { ... }

class CounterElement extends HTMLElement {
  counter = 0;
  seconds = 0;
  #shadow;
  #samp;
  #button;

  constructor() {
    super();

    // Shadow Root
    // ...
    
    let intervalId;
    let intervalStep = () => { // Will be called every second
      this.updateText();
      if (--this.seconds <= 0) {
        clearInterval(this.#intervalId);
        this.#button.disabled = false;
      }
    };
    
    this.#button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.seconds = 60;
      this.counter += 25;
      this.#intervalId = setInterval(intervalStep, 1000);
      this.#button.disabled = true;
      this.updateText();
    });
    
    this.updateText();
  }
  
  // Member-functions ...
}
customElements.define('counter-instance', CounterElement);
```

## Conclusion

As mentioned before, accessing the elements of the shadow root is still possible using the Developer Tools. Fully disabling the ability of changing the button's `disabled`-property can be achieved using a MutationObserver, keeping the property from being changed, depending on what number `seconds` currently has.

Here is the full code as a Stack-Snippet, so you can try it out yourselves:

```js
function formatTime(seconds) {
  var min = new String(Math.floor(seconds / 60));
  var sec = new String(seconds % 60);

  while (min.length < 2) min = '0' + min;
  while (sec.length < 2) sec = '0' + sec;

  return min + ':' + sec;
};

class CounterElement extends HTMLElement {
  counter = 0;
  seconds = 0;
  #shadow;
  #samp;
  #button;
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    // Shadow Root
    this.#shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'closed'});
    
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    let style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML = 'div{padding:0.2rem;border:1px solid black}'
        + 'samp{display:block}button{font-family:monospace}';
    
    this.#samp = document.createElement('samp');
    this.#button = document.createElement('button');
    
    div.append(this.#samp, this.#button);
    this.#shadow.append(style, div);
    
    let intervalId;
    let intervalStep = () => { // Will be called every second
      if (--this.seconds <= 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        this.#button.disabled = false;
      }
      this.updateText();
    };
    
    this.#button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.seconds = 60;
      this.counter += 25;
      intervalId = setInterval(intervalStep, 1000);
      this.#button.disabled = true;
      this.updateText();
    });

    this.updateText();
  }
  
  updateText() {
    this.#samp.innerText = this.counter;
    this.#button.innerText = this.seconds ? formatTime(this.seconds) : 'Collect';
  }
}
customElements.define('counter-instance', CounterElement);
```

```css
/* Ignore; only for styling purposes */
body {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.6rem;
}
```

```html
<!-- Works with multiple elements -->
<counter-instance></counter-instance>
<counter-instance></counter-instance>
```

Comment: Hi Oskar, i'm so sorry i didn't see your answer. Thanks for your effort. This is what i needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```js
const button = document.getElementById("myBtn")

function freeze () {
  button.disabled = true
  setTimeout(function() { 
    button.disabled = false
  }, 60000);
}

button.onclick = function () {
 if(button.disabled) { // Avoid user removing disable in the html
  // Add 25 to whatever
    freeze()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here is your code

```js
$('#btn').prop('disabled',true);
startCountDown();

function getCounter(){
  return  parseInt($('#counter').html());
}
function setCounter(count) {
  $('#counter').html(count);
}

$("#btn").click(function() {
  setCounter(getCounter()+25);
  $('#btn').prop('disabled',true);
  startCountDown();
});

function startCountDown() {
  var minutes = 0,
    seconds = 59;
  $("#countdown").html(minutes + ":" + seconds);
  var count = setInterval(function() {
    if (parseInt(minutes) < 0 || parseInt(seconds) <=0 ) {
      $("#countdown").html(minutes + ":" + seconds);
      clearInterval(count);
      $('#btn').prop('disabled',false);
    } else {
      $("#countdown").html(minutes + ":" + seconds);
      seconds--;
      if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
#counter{
  font-size: 25px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter">0</div>
<button id="btn">
<span id="countdown">0:00</span>
</button>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! But do you know how to make it so that it does not say 0:00 but "Collect"? Sorry, I am new in JavaScript

Comment: [Here is Code Pen link](https://codepen.io/sumit684/pen/yLVLaPO)

You just need to change the code when the clock stops we will overwrite the content of the countdown button as "Collect"

Also, there is a change in HTML we must keep the button disabled at the start so add disabled property in countdown button

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be as follow:

Here your button:

```
<button id="MyBtn" onclick="disable_button_3_secs(); return false;">Disabled me for 3 seconds</button>
```

Here your script:

```
    var timeout_lenght = 3000;
    var myBtn = document.getElementById("MyBtn");

    function disable_button_3_secs() {
        myBtn.disabled = true;
        Enable_at_timer_out();
    }

    function Enable_at_timer_out() {
        setTimeout(function () {myBtn.disabled = false; }, timeout_lenght);
    }
```

I personally like to have more control over my code so I always use variables whenever I can. I have set the timer to 3 seconds but you can change it as you wish.

Davide

Comment: Hi @Davice. Your solution comport some problem. 
Even if you change the ui while adding `disabled: true` an user with the knowledge of html could open the DOM and remove it manually, then the click will work again. You should also control it within the `disable_button_3_secs` method.
Your response also did not contain the +25 logic. I think your response need more detail to be more useful.

Comment: Hi @rbalet, and thanks for pointing that out. I was just trying to keeping it simple as the previous answer look very similar to mine (beside the improvements you suggested).